# Postgresql conditional unique constraint on multiple values

Tags: postgresql, indexing

To achieve a cart process, I want to not allow a user to create several carts.

Cart has several binary statuses, such as `1 : CART` or `1024 : PAYMENT IN PROGRESS`

I have an order table with fields `user_id` and `status`

To trigger a conflict if a user tries to create a new cart if there is already an in progress payment cart, I build this unique constraint

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_cart_idx ON orders (status, user_id) WHERE (status = 1 OR status = 1025);`

But does not work. If I already have a cart with status `1025` (CART | IN PROGRESS), I can create a new cart with status `1` if not exists.

Comment: have you tried CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_cart_idx ON orders (user_id) WHERE (status = 1 OR status = 1025) ?

Comment: When you have a binary status, i would change `(status = 1 OR status = 1025)` to `(status & 1)::bool`

Comment: @Luuk sure, but statuses in this case are combinable and there are many other statuses, such as PLACED = 4. An order can be CART | PLACED. Won't work in this case.

Comment: @DavidMendes works great ^^ tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the index on `user_id` only when ever the status is either of the values: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_nEGD6eJ))

```
create table orders ( id      integer 
                              generated always as identity
                              primary key 
                    , user_id integer
                    , status  integer
                    ) ; 

create unique index user_cart_idx on orders (user_id) where (status = 1 or status = 1025);
```